# How get date less date with time of end day

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I have date_end with time 01.01.2020 11:53, 01.01.2020 14:28, 03.01.2020 09:51, 03.01.2020 06:02, 04.01.2020 19:45. I do

```
date_end < to_date('03.01.2020 23:59', 'dd.mm.yyyy HH24:mi')
```

and i get only 01.01.2020 11:53, 01.01.2020 14:28. How I can all date_end without 04.01.2020

Answer (score 0):

the query looks ok. the only thing you need to check is the datatype of `date_end` column. It is probably not in the datetime format, and It only holds date without time fraction

Comment: I think datatipe is Suitable. When I find by range                                          
** date_trunc('day', .date_end) between to_date('01.01.2020 00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy HH24:mi') and to_date('"03.01.2020' 23:59', 'dd.mm.yyyy HH24:mi')                                      
**                                                                                                                                            Its working